# unable to read another application's caption

Tags: c#, dllimport, user32

Jumping of how i will find windows handle in my main program...

in C#

I run notepad.exe then type something in it,then find the main window handle using SPY++ (0x111111) ,and

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]

internal static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, [Out] StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);
.
.
.
GetWindowText((IntPtr)(0x111111), str, 1024);
```

this code works fine and return me the caption of the main window.

: : but when i do the same to find caption of the child of notepad.exe it just set str to nothing. the spy++ told me that the child's caption has value.

Comment: Which child???? Could range from the File menu option to the status bar or anything in between!

Comment: i wrote something in text area. then use spy++ to find the handle with the text in caption, then use that handle in my code.

Comment: You do realize that the handle (`hWnd`) will not always be the same? Hard-coding the value in your application is useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "most correct" way to do this would be:

```
public static string GetWindowText(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    if (hwnd == IntPtr.Zero)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("hwnd");
    int length = SendMessageGetTextLength(hwnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    if (length > 0 && length < int.MaxValue)
    {
        length++; // room for EOS terminator
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
        SendMessageGetText(hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, (IntPtr)sb.Capacity, sb);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    return String.Empty;
}

const int WM_GETTEXT = 0x000D;
const int WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0x000E;

[DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
extern static int SendMessageGetTextLength(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
[DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
extern static IntPtr SendMessageGetText(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, [Out] StringBuilder lParam);
[DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
extern static IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, [In] string lpClassName, [In] string lpWindowName);
```

Note the use of `[In]` and `[Out]` attributes to eliminate unnecessary copying during marshalling.

Also note that you should never expose p/invoke methods to the outside world (not public).

Comment: could you please provide me some hints on how to find latest change on my textbox ? i have a growing textbox ,can i link something to event list of that textbox or something like this?

Comment: There is no change notification on the system EDIT control that could be monitored by an external process. You can poll it, or you could write a global hook to implement such an event. That hook would a CBT_CALLWNDPROCRET. This requires writing a native DLL (i.e. C/C++) and is complicated if the process being hooked is both 32- and 64-bit as Notepad is.

Answer (score 4):

The [GetWindowText function documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) clearly states that "GetWindowText cannot retrieve the text of a control in another application. ... To retrieve the text of a control in another process, send a WM_GETTEXT message directly instead of calling GetWindowText."

You can retrieve the control's text with the following code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessageGetText(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, UIntPtr wParam, StringBuilder lParam);

const uint WM_GETTEXT = 13;
const int bufferSize = 1000; // adjust as necessary
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bufferSize);
SendMessageGetText(hWnd, WM_GETTEXT, new UIntPtr(bufferSize), sb);
string controlText = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: The wParam argument is IntPtr.  Return value too, doesn't matter much in this case.

Comment: @Hans Thanks; I corrected the signature to match the documented types LRESULT (LONG_PTR), UINT, and WPARAM (UINT_PTR).

Comment: Thanks , it works, could you please tell me how can i find the length of the text before reading, or how can i read the tail of the text?

Comment: @amir: You are trying to dig into the internals of another program. This is obviously undefined territory. You should rethink your solution.

Comment: @amir: Use WM_GETTEXTLENGTH (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632628(v=vs.85).aspx).