# How to get Window name in c++

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a window handle (HWND) of Text-box Control. I had have the window handle using EnumChildWindows Function. When I try to get the caption(Text) of the control using GetWindowText it always return null.

Its actually correct, because text box's default Text may be null.

Is there any Function to get name of text Field like GetWindowText. I don't want the text I want only the name.

Comment: If the text box is empty then GetWindowText will give you an empty.  However, I think you are possibly being confused with the concept of name.  Do you mean you want the text of a nearby label perhaps?

Comment: Controls do not have names, unless you are referring to the [UIA_NamePropertyId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684017.aspx#UIA_NamePropertyId) offered through [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The text box itself will not hold the caption. That will be a label adjacent to the text box. You can use EnumChildWindows to find that control and extract the caption.

Comment: I know the caption of label nearer to it. But using that how can you know the next controls name??? it does not possible here?  @Bathsheba

Answer (score -2):

The Textbox must be owned by the application. If you try to get the text from control of other window, you will get 0. However it can be done with DLL injection, etc.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. How do you think Spy++ works?

Comment: @Bathsheba Because I have tried to do the same 15 years ago and know the limitations.

Comment: `If the target window is owned by the current process, GetWindowText causes a WM_GETTEXT message to be sent to the specified window or control. If the target window is owned by another process and has a caption, GetWindowText retrieves the window caption text. If the window does not have a caption, the return value is a null string. This behavior is by design.` --- See [GetWindowText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @i486 When I use GetWindowText Function , it return the exact text for label . but text-box returns always null.

Comment: This is content protection. In Windows95/98 there is no such "problem" but in Windows NT (2000/XP) you cannot simply get other's Textbox (EDIT control) contents. Look in Codeproject for DLL injection hack. Note that it may not work for x64 or Windows 8.

Comment: Or use SendMessage, such as `auto result = ::SendMessageW(handle, WM_GETTEXT, sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(buffer[0]), ::LPARAM(buffer));`

Comment: `GetWindowText` does the same `WM_GETTEXT`.

Comment: `GetWindowText()` works fine across processes ([and does not sent a WM_GETTEXT to do its thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/08/21/54675.aspx))

Comment: You can get text and data from other processes sending messages instead of using GetWindowText()
Maybe duplicated from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604023/unable-to-read-another-applications-caption

Comment: @TagFolks See this: http://www.ucancode.net/Visual_C_Control/Window-hook-GetWindowHookEx-WM_GETTEXT-Password-VC-Example.htm