# Get form handle from point using pinvoke

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

I'm trying to get a window handle from point using p/invoke, where window is a form, and not any child control. I have a simple interface where X and Y are entered by user, and then Find button is used to call win32 and get necessary information. My problem is that window is not necessarily a form, it can also be a control. See below screenshot - at (100,100) happened to be Notepad's text area with "StackOverflow" written in it. As a result, Found window shows "StackOverflow".

[image]

Is there any way I can restrict window type to be a Form? Expected result is "Untitled - Notepad" for below test case. Alternatively, is there a way to ask another application's control to provide its form's handle? In short, I need to get form's title from (x,y) point. Button click handler code:

```
private void btn_Find_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int xPoint = Convert.ToInt32(txt_WindowX.Text);
  int yPoint = Convert.ToInt32(txt_WindowY.Text);

  IntPtr hWnd = Win32.GetWindowHandleFromPoint(xPoint, yPoint);
  txt_FormTitle.Text = Win32.GetWindowTitle(hWnd);
}
```

Major portion of Win32 class comes from this answer:

- [Tergiver's answer to "C# - unable to read another application's caption"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4606076/897326)

Full Win32 class code is provided below:

```
public class Win32
{
  /// <summary>
  /// 
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="hwnd"></param>
  /// <remarks>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604023/unable-to-read-another-applications-caption</remarks>
  public static string GetWindowTitle(IntPtr hwnd)
  {
    if (hwnd == IntPtr.Zero)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("hwnd");
    int length = Win32.SendMessageGetTextLength(hwnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    if (length > 0 && length < int.MaxValue)
    {
      length++; // room for EOS terminator
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
      Win32.SendMessageGetText(hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, (IntPtr)sb.Capacity, sb);
      return sb.ToString();
    }
    return String.Empty;
  }

  public static IntPtr GetWindowHandleFromPoint(int x, int y)
  {
    var point = new Point(x, y);
    return Win32.WindowFromPoint(point);
  }

  const int WM_GETTEXT = 0x000D;
  const int WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0x000E;

  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  private static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(Point p);

  [DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
  private static extern int SendMessageGetTextLength(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
  [DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
  private static extern IntPtr SendMessageGetText(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, [Out] StringBuilder lParam);
}
```

Comment: Can you get the Control from the handle using Control FromHandle(IntPtr handle) and check the Type of the Control to see if it is a Form? If its not a Form you can use the Parent property of the Control and iterate up through the tree until you've found the Form.

Comment: @LindosPechos: This seems to work only if handle belongs to my application. Otherwise Control.FromHandle returns null.

Comment: GetParent(hWnd) != null? to find the top level window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to locate the top level window. Start from the window that `GetWindowHandleFromPoint` yielded. Then call `GetParent` repeatedly until you find a window with no parent. That window with no parent is the top level window that you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! You can also add some code for future visitors. I could not find anything better than a while loop with repeated reversed condition in the nested if - maybe you can suggest a cleaner approach (without recursion). http://pastebin.com/i2Vea4FS

Comment: Your code is fine. I'd probably check FindWindow against null and bail early, then use while (true)